# Using Eclipse as commercial IDE without open-sourcing code

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse, ide, licensing

My company is now chooisng a new IDE mainly for editing PHP/HTML/JavaScript scripts withing a certain web app ( bussines processes ). Can we use Eclipse under [EPL](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php) since we wre only going to use it's php and js plugins for editor, without releasing our code? If not, are there any alternatives? [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is too expensive for our young company.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this?

> According to article 1(b) of the EPL, additions to the original work
>   may be licensed independently, including under a proprietary license,
>   provided such additions are "separate modules of software" and do not
>   constitute a derivative work.Changes and additions which do constitute
>   a derivative work must be licensed under the same terms and conditions
>   of the EPL, which includes the requirement to make source code
>   available.

And this:

> The Eclipse Public License is designed to be a business-friendly free
>   software license and features weaker copyleft provisions than
>   contemporary licenses such as the GNU General Public License (GPL).
>   The receiver of EPL-licensed programs can use, modify, copy and
>   distribute the work and modified versions, in some cases being
>   obligated to release their own changes.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License

Also if you are looking for alternatives maybe you should check out Netbeans.